# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. when i set multi flavorDimensions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-flavordimension

When I use one flavorDimensions, everything is ok.

```
flavorDimensions("aaa")//everything run
```

but when I use multi flavorDimensions and sync project.

It sync fail and get the error `A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.`
[image]
Does anyone know how to solve the problems?